# How to groupby maximum date in Python

Tags: python

I want to use the groupby function in Python. I have a csv file which has millions of rows and there are only 2 columns called 'Arrangement' and Date. Each arrangement number has multiple dates. If even one date in an arrangement falls after 1st July, 2018, I need to make a new column and flag the entire arrangement as YES. If all of the dates in an arrangement fall before 1st July, 2018 then I have to flag that as NO.

I am trying to group arrangement using groupby and aggregation by finding out the maximum date in each arrangement but it's not working.

[this is just an example of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1Sw4.png)

Comment: "I am trying to group arrangement using groupby and aggregation by finding out the maximum date in each arrangement but it's not working." ... if you are looking for help then post how you are trying to enable people to support you. Start by posting your code to show what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solutions I have at the moment

```
condition_df = df.groupby('arrangement')['date'].apply(lambda d: 'YES' if max(d) > pd.to_datetime('2018-08-01') else 'NO').rename(columns={'date': 'in_db'})
condition_df.reset_index()
```

The result is

```
   arrangement in_db
0          123  YES
1          234   NO
2          456  YES
```

you can join back on the original df. How this scales with the number of rows, you have to determine.